# Why is the user inputted number not appearing in the java cell?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cell

I am trying to create a game, I have the code below set for the cells I want the user to be able to input into, which seems to be working as if I type anything other than numbers 1-5 in the cells, I get the appropriate error message, but the input typed just isn't appearing on the screen... how do I make it so the number inputted shows up in the selected cell?

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
     char i =(e.getKeyChar());
     trace("i: "+i);
     if ((i!='1')&&(i!='2')&&(i!='3')&&(i!='4')&&(i!='5')){
         panel.setStatus("Invalid input");
     return;
 }
 panel.makeMove(row,col);
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the return, you should get the expected result.
Return in a method will stop the execution of the rest of the code so your final line is never being called if you enter 1 through 5.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
     char i =(e.getKeyChar());
     trace("i: "+i);
     if ((i!='1')&&(i!='2')&&(i!='3')&&(i!='4')&&(i!='5')){
         panel.setStatus("Invalid input");
     }
...
```

Seems to be some context missing from the question, how you're setting the cell, etc, but with the information given, this should be correct, let me know if I'm wrong!